# How can I run JS code only if a DIV exists

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Using the below code. It is used to fix a navbar to the top of the browser once a user starts scrolling down. This is not on every page though (myHeader div) so it's showing a missing error. Can I amend this code to only run if the myHeader div exists?

```
<script>window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
function myFunction() { if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
header.classList.add("sticky-solution");} else {
header.classList.remove("sticky-solution");}}
</script>
```

Comment: You've tagged [tag:jquery] so there's a jquery solution, but it also has vanilla js answers.

Comment: Note: if you did use jquery, you wouldn't need to worry about it as it would just have no effect `$("#myHeader").addClass("sticky")` would do nothing if no myHeader

Comment: If the error is just telling you that `header` is `null` then you could simply check if `header` is `null` before trying to use it...